# How do I solve my error of npm start(webpack-cli, typeError) after doing dfx deploy

Tags: npm

this image shows the error exactly

No production canister_ids.json found. Continuing with local
[webpack-cli] TypeError: cli.isMultipleCompiler is not a function
at Command. (/home/dg/ic-projects/hello/node_modules/@webpack-cli/serve/lib/index.js:146:35)
at async Promise.all (index 1)
at async Command. (/home/dg/ic-projects/hello/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:1672:7)

Answer (score 2):

Installing webpack-cli 4.10.0 should solve the problem.
Just run npm i `webpack-cli@4.10.0`